# Objective C Help (Newbie)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Ok so Im brand new to objective C and to give myself a little practice I made a small little program. The programs suppose to figure out how many days old are you. I have this error that I cannot figure out. Heres the code:

**Age.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Age : NSObject {
int age;
int age365;
int lyear;
}
-(void) howOld;


@end
```

**Age.m**

```
#import "Age.h"

@implementation Age


-(void) howOld{
NSLog(@"How old are you currently?\n");
scanf("age");
NSLog(@"You entered %i", age);



}


@end
```

**Month.h**

```
#import "Age.h"

@interface Month : Age{
int month;
}

-(void) whatMonth;

@end
```

**Month.m**

```
#import "Month.h"

@implementation Month

-(void) whatMonth{

NSLog(@"What month is it? (Number)\n");
scanf("month");
NSLog(@"you entered %i", month);



}


@end
```

**Day.h**

```
#import "Month.h"

@interface Day : Month{
int day;
}
-(void) whatDay;
-(void) printAge;
@end
```

**Day.m**

```
#import "Day.h"

@implementation Day

-(void) whatDay{
NSLog(@"What day is it? (Number)");
scanf("day");
NSLog(@"You entered %i", day);
day = month*30+day+age365;

}

-(void) printAge{
age365 = age * 365;
lyear = age/4;
age = lyear + age365;
NSLog(@"You are %i days old", day);
}

@end
```

**Main.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Age.h"
#import "Month.h"
#import "Day.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

    Age *a = [[Age alloc]init];

    [a howOld];


    Month *m = [[Month alloc]init];

    [m whatMonth];

    Day *d = [[Day alloc]init];

    [d whatDay];
    [d printAge];


}
return 0;
}
```

**Output**
**HERES THE ERROR**

```
**Lets me type**(
2013-08-08 17:27:26.121 HMDAI[10989:303] How old are you currently?
3)

**Does by itself**(
2013-08-08 17:27:43.854 HMDAI[10989:303] You entered 0
2013-08-08 17:27:43.854 HMDAI[10989:303] What month is it? (Number)
2013-08-08 17:27:43.855 HMDAI[10989:303] you entered 0
2013-08-08 17:27:43.855 HMDAI[10989:303] What day is it? (Number)
2013-08-08 17:27:43.855 HMDAI[10989:303] You entered 0
2013-08-08 17:27:43.856 HMDAI[10989:303] You are 0 days old
)
```

What did I do wrong? I used XCode if that helps.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the error was.  You could also help us out a bit by telling us where the error occurred.

Comment: Plenty of information to solve the question; you just need to be a unix neckbeard to know the answer.   Fortunately, I haven't shaved this week...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` means *scan formatted string from standard input*.   The function takes a format string and a set of pointers to scan stuff into.

Your code is failing because you aren't telling `scanf()` that it should scan for a number.

The wikipedia article is actually quite informative:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string

(And a lot less dense than the typical man page that us neckbeards live and die by).

---

Note that if your goal is to learn ObjC for the purposes of Mac OS X or iOS programming, you've picked a fine, but odd, place to start.   You'd be better off starting with one of the numerous *how to write apps* tutorials.

Comment: Nothing wrong with starting where you are, just that standard I/O based interactivity is far removed from iOS/OS X app programming.  There are tons of tutorials out there.  Which to go for? I'd lean to one that starts more at the basic app level.  Which one?  No idea -- been decades since I've seriously reviewed or used such tutorials.   I have ended up on this site when I explored Cocos2d a while ago (http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials).